# discord.py AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'commands'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to do commands to discord.py in other file but when i try to setup them i get error
'Client' object has no attribute 'add_cog'
My main.py file:

```
import discord
import music
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
token = ""

cogs = [music]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.load_extension(cogs.commands)
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user})")
    








client.run(token)
```

music.py file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("First join to voice channel")
            voicechannel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            if ctx.voicechannel is None:
                await voicechannel.join()
            else:
                await voicechannel.move_to(ctx.voicechannel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn' }
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client 
        
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, 
            **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("resumed")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("paused")





async def setup(client):
   await client.add_cog(music(client))
```

I pasted everything from my file

The error:
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'load_extension'
I tried to use help from similar thread but it wasnt working

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please give the full code? We don't know how client is called or other things that could help us find the error.

Answer (score 0):

following your code, this is an **outdated** version of cog loading/setting. according to the new [Migrations](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous) made by python you will need to re-edit your code to move smoothly with the migration.

```
async def setup(client):
   await client.add_cog(commands(client))
```

and in your Main.py file, along with your **on_ready** add this:

```
await client.load_extension("cogs.commands")
```

Please don't hesitate to comment on this post if there is any more requests :D

Goodluck!

Comment: When i added await client.load_extension("cogs.commands") in main file i get AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'load_extension'

Comment: can you please edit your post to the current modifications?

Comment: Yes i updated thread

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `main.py` says (Line 12):

> await client.load_extension(cogs.commands)

you cannot use `discord.Client` to load an extension. What you must do is use `commands.Bot`. This was a problem I have recently found myself. To fix this you can change your 5th line from

> client = **discord.Client**(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

to

> client = **commands.Bot**(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

I hope this works. If you have any issues or don't understand just comment on this post and I will try to help you.

Comment: Now i get something like that ```module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'```

Comment: Can you update the thread with your current code and the full error so I can see what the problem is now

Comment: Yes sure i updated.

Comment: It is `commands. Bot` not `discord. Bot`

Comment: I get now something else i updated thread

Comment: Alright this is where I dont understand fully and would love someone else who understands to tell us. I would like to tell you to replace client with bot but i have no idea how client is different to bot